# Magento 1.9 - Multiple Storeviews for the same Languages

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, multistore, localisation

I've got a settings-related question for you all; we have a Magento 1.9 shop with something of the following store setup:

- Store 1 - Storeview 1 - Language A
- Store 1 - Storeview 1 - Language B
- Store 1 - Storeview 1 - Language C
- Store 1 - Storeview 1 - Language D
- -
- Store 1 - Storeview 2 - Language A
- Store 1 - Storeview 2 - Language B
- Store 1 - Storeview 2 - Language C
- Store 1 - Storeview 2 - Language D
- etc

And this goes on for some storeviews.

The point being is that the site actually only has 4 different languages, but because they also have 6 storeviews with those languages, I have a lot of duplicates (24 seperate language fields, for only 4 languages).

I.e. when I translate an attribute I have to set translations for a single item 26 times where it could be 4.
I'm thinking of a fix [like this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76587/with-multi-store-how-do-i-ensure-only-one-set-of-cache-images-are-created) (a single cache for the whole site and all productimages instead of a cache per storeview), but then for the attribute-translations?

[image: In example a attribute-value screen]

*Edit* - Or am I approaching this the wrong way and should I just leave all the specific back-end translations empty, and go about to translating via .csv files?